# Conditional Probability with median of numbers

Tags: probability-theory

Given an array of numbers with length $n$, take 3 random values and find the median value. What is the probability that this given element is in the middle range for our array, that is, its index is $n/4 \le i < 3n/4$?

I know the probability of a given number being within this range is $1/2$, but I struggle on knowing where to go from here ...

Comment: Don't vandalize posts on this site, not even your own.

Answer (score 3):

Let's label the ranges of the indices into low $[1,\ n/4)$, middle $[n/4,\ 3n/4 )$ and high of $[3n/4,\ n]$.

Thinking through a few examples, if you have $2$ of your $3$ samples in the low range, or in the high range, it's impossible for the median of your samples to be in the middle range. And the only way that the median is in the center range is (a) if two or three samples fall in the middle range or (b) there is exactly one sampled number in each section of the indicies.

You merely just need to calculate the probability that there are no more than $1$ samples in each of the low and high ranges, and you will have your result.